# "pantheon-filechooser-module" error on Elementary OS Freya

Tags: release-freya

When I run an app on terminal I can, but I get the next error

> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This will happen for any non-gtk3 app. It is a non-fatal warning and can be ignored